# R pheatmap How to plot a linear model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, cluster-analysis, heatmap, pheatmap

I have a classical linear model y ~ x1 + x2. How can I plot a heatmap of this model?
Normally I print a heatmap from data in this way:

```
library(pheatmap)

data <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3), x1=c(1.5,2,2.5), x2=c(3,10,12))
pheatmap(cor(data), scale="none")
```

But in this case I want to see the effect of y on x1 and x2. So I need a heatmap with a covariate for y. Something like this:

```
pheatmap(cor(select(data,-c(y))), scale="none", covariate=y)
```

But i didn't find a correct syntax for y as covariate. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (where `y` is `qsec`, `x1` is `hp` and `x2` is `wt`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

mod <- lm(qsec ~ hp + wt, data=mtcars)

hp_s <- seq(min(mtcars$hp), max(mtcars$hp), length=25)
wt_s <- seq(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt), length=25)

eg <- expand_grid(hp = hp_s, wt=wt_s)
eg$fit <- predict(mod, newdata=eg)

ggplot(eg, aes(x=hp, y=wt, fill=fit)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to show the data with a heatmap - more precisely with the pheatmap function. I think it is possible with the parameters annotation_col and annotation_row but actually I don't know how.

Comment: @user3351676 what do you want the two axes of the heat map to be and to what quantity do you want the coolers to correspond?